# How to do a turn a drop down into a list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to turn the following drop down statement into a list, how would i do this:

```
<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.joins(:live_player).where(:teamid => @ids).all, "playerid", "Plyr") %>
```

I tried putting it into a loop but it just came back empty, see below:

`<select id = "Plyrs" style = float:middle size = 10>
    <% Teamplayer.joins(:live_player).where(:teamid => @ids).all do |f| %>
        <option><%= f.Plyr %> <%#= p.Team %></option>
    <% end %>
    </select>`

what am i doing wrong, because I can run it from the console, but not in my html

Comment: Side Note: You should query the database in your controller and create an instance variable.

Comment: then i can loop through that instance variable?

Comment: Yes. Anyways why are you commenting `p.Team`?

Comment: I commented the p.Team because i did not need it at the moment, but it's as a reminder in my code to use it when i get it working

Comment: Also i can look the the instance variable like this: `<% @v.each do |some| %>`

Answer (score 0):

As long as I can see you want to change a dropdown text. The best way to do that is keep using the helper, and create a model method that returns the name you want it to show:

```
  <%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(@TeamPlayers, "playerid", "PlayerAndTeam") %>
```

And in your model

```
def PlayerAndTeam
  self.Plyr + ' ' + self.Team #you can use joins and such, I find this easier to understand.
end
```

I hope this helps.

GL & HF.